# Ext GWT 2 - Group grid rows

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

Is it possible to group Grid rows by column values?

For example I have this `ModelData`:

```
    ModelData model = new BaseModelData();

    Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String,String>();
    data.put("Date", "20:55:06");
    data.put("Service", "1001");
    data.put("IP", "127.0.0.1:5003"); 
    data.put("Status", "Good");
    data.put("Code", "0200");

    for (Entry<String, String> entry: data.entrySet()) {
        model.set(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
```

And I have a `List<ModelData>` which is rendered to a Grid, and what I need is to **group** rows in the Grid having the same "IP", "Status" and "Code" for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You can group items in Ext GWT 2 Grids as shown here.](http://www.sencha.com/examples-2/#grouping)

You need to create an instance of [the `GroupingView` class](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/gxt-2.2.5/docs/api/com/extjs/gxt/ui/client/widget/grid/GroupingView.html) as pass it to your `Grid`.

If you don't need to display the Group headers then just sort the `ModelData` objects before adding them to the `Grid`.

Comment: Yah... I don't need Group headers

Answer (score 0):

I think [AggregationRowConfig](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/gxt-2.2.5/docs/api/com/extjs/gxt/ui/client/widget/grid/AggregationRowConfig.html) is what you need.